# Select2 - How to get the value of an item within an optgroup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I seem to be having an issue with Select2 that's in multiple mode and getting the value from it.

There are many Q&A's on SO that imply that you can do:

```
$(selector).select2("val");
```

to get the value of the select2.  This doesn't work for me, it just returns `""`, however I have had success with using

```
$(selector).select2("data");
```

and then picking out the selected items.

However, if my list uses `optgroup`, then I cannot get a value from it via either of the above methods, making it impossible to know what the value is.

I'm populating the Select2 by passing an array of objects to it via the data property when initialising the control, e.g:

```
var myArray = [{id: "1", text: "Foo"}, {id: "2", text: "Bar"}];
$(selector).select2({data: myArray});
```

**Edit - Issue Resolved**

So basically I was being a bit of an idiot.

I'm implementing the Select2 control in ReactJS and wrapping it in the relevant elements that our UI designers have provided.  I'd realised that I'd put the id that I was using as the selector on the parent `SPAN` and not on the select itself.  So of course, when trying to get the value it would always return `""`.

```
$(selector).select2("val");
```

now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `select2` selected value using jquery `option:selected` and get `val`

**jQuery**

```
$('#select2').select2();
$('#select2').on('change', function(){
    alert($("#select2 option:selected").val()) 
});
```

You can checkout [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tu9h5zu8/1/)

Comment: Although this wasn't the solution to my problem, it works and it did actually made me realise what I was doing wrong, I'll update my question in a sec.